# Linq to Entities : relationship * - *

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have on my EF Schema a relationship * - * (designed by a middle table with 2 keys).
When I want filter on each (ie : I want all market segment filtered by one function), I execute this query :

```
 var requete = from mkt in ent.MARKETSEGMENT_MKT
 where mkt.FUNCTION2_FUN.Where(fu => fu.FUN_ID == FunId).FirstOrDefault().FUN_ID == FunId
```

It's working, but it's ugly. How to craft a good query for filtered relationship * - * ?

Thank you

Comment: you should use a join on your many-to-many relationship...

Comment: @Tony, I strongly disagree with that: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's almost never correct to use `join`](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/) in LINQ to Entities (or LINQ to SQL).

Since you don't specify your entity set names, I have to guess. I hope this makes sense:

```
var requete = from fun in ent.FUNCTION
              where fun.FUN_ID == FunId
              from mkt in fun.MARKETSEGMENT_MKT
              select mkt;
```

The important point here is that you have a *two way* association between `FUNCTION` and `MARKETSEGMENT`. Use it!

Comment: Thank you, I understand better the concept now :)

Answer (score 0):

use the Join method.

this tiny example from nerddinner.com might help:

```
 var dinners = from dinner in FindUpcomingDinners()
        join i in db.NearestDinners(latitude, longitude)
        on dinner.DinnerID equals i.DinnerID
        select dinner;
```

Comment: I try with a join but no success 

var requete = from mkt in ent.MARKETSEGMENT_MKT
join fun in ent.FUNCTION2_FUN on mkt.MKT_ID equals fun.MARKETSEGMENT_MKT. <= What I can insert here, it's a IEnumerable and not an Id